# Populate ReportViewer manually

Tags: c#, mysql, reportviewer

I need to fill a Report Viewer manunualy i mean do not create a DataSet by the Wizard  but all by code. I'm using visual studio 2010 C# + MySql

Actually I need to create a report viewer with a filter (Current DateTime) 
If you have a better suggestion for my problem i'd be thankfull

Thanks in advance

Comment: Start with http://gotreportviewer.com/ and comeback here when You get stacked

Comment: Thanks for answering me adopilot1 but it only shows WHAT TO DO not HOW TO DO and I'm a begginer programmer. So do not know much yet =\

Comment: -1 This question is not specific enough (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Please consider reading some of the documentation for the ReportViewer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671.aspx) and then revising your question to ask a specific question. See http://www.WhatHaveYouTried.com

Comment: I Just need to filter my ReportViewer by DateTime, and to do that. I Guess its necessary create a DataSource Manually for the reportviewer. And i'm trying do that but i didnt sucess =\\

Answer (score 0):

ReprotViewer can use DataTable as report source, In one of your questions you already populate datatable from MYSQL you When You have data table with data inside.  Then you need to tell report viewer to use your datattable as data source.
I suggest you to download sample projects http://gotreportviewer.com/Objectds.zip and http://gotreportviewer.com/InvoiceMaker.zip and to see how they applying  data source to reports.